# ZendFramework not redirecting to action url => controller/action

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I created a Controller in my application called UserController and Created a bunch of Actions in them which are empty at the moment. I used `zf create controll user` and `zf create action new user`

I created a virtual host 'aman_proj'

When I type in the url 'aman_proj/' It displays the index.php page in /public.

But when I type in 'aman_proj/user/new', It still displays the index.php file in /public.

Can anyone help me why this is happening. I am pasting my index.php code below, let me know if you need to see more code. My controller has action but they are all empty. I have their view in view/scripts/user/new.phtml

```
//public/index.php

<?php
echo "<b>This is Zend Home Page located in /public/index.php</b><br>";

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

echo "APPLICATION_PATH : ".APPLICATION_PATH."<br>";

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

echo "APPLICATION_ENV : ".APPLICATION_ENV."<br>";

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

echo "Paths : ".get_include_path()."<br>"; 

/** Zend_Application */
echo require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Comment: Try the url `aman_proj/index.php/user/new`. If this works then please  make sure your `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: my mod_rewrite is also enabled. and the url aman_proj/index.php/user/new does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I can't see anything wrong with your index.php file, and if you aren't getting the error pages it sounds like the the requests aren't getting rewritten.